# Correct way to use %in% multiple times

Tags: r, subset

I am new to R and I have written the following piece of code. However, I believe there might be a better way of implementing the following code:

In the code I copied and pasted one code multiple times to filter out different observations from the same variables. I tried using %notin% but it does not seem to work for me

```
select.other <- have_data[which(have_data$TOP_NM == 'Other'),names(have_data) %in% c("TOP_NM","SERIES_NM","SERIES_VAL","RANK")]
select.other <- select.other[which(select.other$SERIES_NM != 'Constant=1 in Q1'),names(select.other) %in% c("TOP_NM","SERIES_NM","SERIES_VAL","RANK")]
select.other <- select.other[which(select.other$SERIES_NM != 'Constant=1 in Q2'),names(select.other) %in% c("TOP_NM","SERIES_NM","SERIES_VAL","RANK")]
select.other <- select.other[which(select.other$SERIES_NM != 'Constant=1 in Q3'),names(select.other) %in% c("TOP_NM","SERIES_NM","SERIES_VAL","RANK")]
select.other <- select.other[which(select.other$SERIES_NM != 'Constant=1 in Q4'),names(select.other) %in% c("TOP_NM","SERIES_NM","SERIES_VAL","RANK")]
select.other <- select.other[which(select.other$SERIES_NM != 'Time: Quarterly'),names(select.other) %in% c("TOP_NM","SERIES_NM","SERIES_VAL","RANK")]
select.other <- select.other[which(select.other$SERIES_NM != 'Time: Quarterly Projected'),names(select.other) %in% c("TOP_NM","SERIES_NM","SERIES_VAL","RANK")]
select.other
```

Hopefully there is a simpler approach would give me the same result. Thanks in advance for any help and guidance

Comment: "Not in" would be `!(x %in% y)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After the first filter, we can create a vector of elements ('v1') to create a logical vector (`%in%`) and then negate (`!`) for subsetting the rows that doesn't have these elements in 'TOP_NM' column

```
v1 <- c('Constant=1 in Q1', 'Constant=1 in Q2', 'Constant=1 in Q3', 
     'Constant=1 in Q4', 'Time: Quarterly', 'Time: Quarterly Projected')
i1 <- !select.other$TOP_NM %in% v1
colsOfInterest <- c("TOP_NM","SERIES_NM","SERIES_VAL","RANK")
select.other[i1, colsOfInterest, drop = FALSE]
```

Note - Here we assume that all the elements in 'colssOfInterest' are matching with the column names of the data.  If not, then either use `intersect(names(select.other), colsOfInterest)` or the OP's code with `%in%`